# git filter-repo: but follow a file if it has moved like git log --follow

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

In my use case, I have been using git filter-repo to select individual files to move to a new repo preserving history. I have a file that has moved once and am struggling to figure out how to get the history from when it was at a different location.
`git log --follow inc/help.py` gives two histories.

If I run `git filter-repo --path inc/help.py`, I am only getting the second history the one when the file was moved. I am struggling to find a way to follow a file that has been moved. Something like `git filter-repo --follow --path inc/help.py` would be helpful if some combination of commands could get the desired results.

Comment: For completeness, https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/297.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround, hope it helps:

https://github.com/rainlabs-eu/git-relevant-history

Basically it uses `git log --follow` to create a list of all past file names and passes it to git filter-repo

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot on my next filter. I went without the --follow last time because I had to get it done.